# Getting Error in the following php code

Tags: php, sql, pdo

`$db` contains the connection to the database.
I am getting the Error in The `foreach` statement.

Error Message :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid        parameter number' in /home/a5057270/public_html/insert2.php:33 Stack trace: #0 /home/a5057270/public_html/insert2.php(33): unknown() #1 {main} thrown in /home/a5057270/public_html/insert2.php on line
```

Here's The PHP code :

```
$date = $_GET['date'];
$time = $_GET['time'];
$mode = $_GET['mode'];
$tfno = $_GET['tfno'];

$params = array(':date' => $date);
$query = "SELECT * FROM cabs WHERE DATE=':date' ";

if ($mode!=='' || $mode!=="") {
  $query .="AND MODE=':mode' ";
  $params[':mode'] = $mode;
}

if ($tfno!=='') {
  $query .="AND TFNO=':tfno' ";
  $params[':tfno'] = $tfno;
}
$query .="ORDER BY TIME";

$req = $db->prepare($query);
$req->execute($params);

//Build Result String
$display_string = "<article class='container box style3'><section><header><h3><u><b>Here Are The Results...!!</u></b></h3></header><div class='table-wrapper'><table class='default'><thead><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Description</th><th>Contact No.</th></tr></thead><tbody>";

// Getting Error in the line Below

foreach ($req as $row) {
   $display_string .="<tr><td>" . $row[IDNO] . "</td><td>" . $row[NAME] . "</td><td><ul><li> Date : " . $row[DATE] . "</li><li> Time : " . $row[TIME] . "</li><li> 

Train/Flight No. " . $row[TFNO] . "</li></ul></td><td>" . $row[CONTACT] . "</td></tr>";


}


$display_string .= "</table>";
```

Comment: you freaking kidding me? "foreach statement not supported by my host?" that too in bold :|

Comment: haha..no i was wrong....i had the suspicion becuz i am using a free host

Comment: to free hosting users like you. A hundred dollar tip : Download WAMPserver and practice PHP with your localhost. It runs without internet and supports all features(more than that) of a free host. I also used free hosts but they suck when I was a learner. They will delete your databases without you even knowing and you never know when these servers get down. Go google wampserver its only 40 mbs and very easy to set up. Yeah you can thank me

Comment: i have wamp in my laptop..but its an outdated version that doesnt suppot PDO...i have to download the new one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's because you are putting `''` around your `PDO` vars... 
remove them and all is good. **example:** make ':mode' => :mode with no `''` and it will work.

```
$params = array(':date' => $date);
$query = "SELECT * FROM cabs WHERE DATE=:date "; //No '' here

if ($mode!=='' || $mode!=="") {
   $query .="AND MODE=:mode "; //No '' here
   $params[':mode'] = $mode;
}

if ($tfno!=='') {
   $query .="AND TFNO=:tfno ";//No '' here
   $params[':tfno'] = $tfno;
}
```

Comment: ya did so for all of them

Comment: sure! all pdo variables shouldn't be surrounded by `''` PDO will do the job for you

Comment: $query = "SELECT * FROM cabs WHERE DATE=':date' "; remove quotes from this also...?

Comment: yes yes all PDO variables shouldn't have `''` if not PDO will consider them as strings => PDO thinks that's what you want to insert